# Warm Winter Muff

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> Some think me clever, some think me sly
>   Some think me pretty, fetching to the eye
>
> Some think me quick, I fear not enough
>   For some think me best a warm winter muff

---

This is my first one so please be nice.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I wonder whether you are

> a fox.

Some think me clever, some think me sly

> Traditional attributes of the fox.

Some think me pretty, fetching to the eye

> Well, they are. Also, "foxy" is a (now rather old-fashioned, I think) term used by men to describe women they find attractive in a certain way.

Some think me quick, I fear not enough

> Foxes are also traditionally described as quick, but ...

For some think me best a warm winter muff

> ... after one has been caught by hunters its fur may be used to make a muff.

Comment: For `Some think me quick, I fear not enough` I think the reference is 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'

Comment: Yes, that's possible. But that sentence exists partly because foxes already had the reputation of being quick :-).

Comment: Yep. Maybe too easy. Outfoxed or sly like a fox, foxy, and the quick brown fox were the main things. And it turns out they'll make anything out of a fox but muff was the best I could do.

Comment: Rhymes nicely with "enough".